# Display character " inside JsonResponse message

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm working on an API using PHP and Symfony where I need to throw some error messages.

I'm working with this method, which I call when error conditions happened:

```
public function error($codeError, $message, $statusCode): JsonResponse
{
    return new JsonResponse([
        'code' => $codeError,
        'description' => $message
    ], $statusCode);
}
```

The thing is, in the variable `$message`, there are some cases that I need to throw a message like `Variable "user" is invalid`, so I pass the string `'Variable "user" is invalid'`. But the `JsonResponse`'s boy I'm getting is: `"description": "Variable \"user\" is invalid"`.

How can I make it look well, without the two `\`?

An example of calling this function would be:

```
return (new ErrTC)->error('AUTH_ERROR', 'Variable "user" is invalid', 401);
```

Comment: What is in $message variable?

Comment: @PHPHuppTechnologies a string. An example when calling this function could be: `return (new ErrTC)->error('AUTH_ERROR', 'Variable "user" is invalid', 401);`.

Comment: is it static string?  'Variable "user" is invalid'

Comment: @PHPHuppTechnologies yes, it is.

Comment: can we pass like return (new ErrTC)->error('AUTH_ERROR', 'Variable user is invalid', 401);

Comment: @PHPHuppTechnologies no... We need to use the `""` characters. The only possible string to return needs to be `Variable "user" is invalid`.

Comment: Please try:
return new JsonResponse([
  'code' => $codeError,
  'description' => htmlentities($message)
], $statusCode);

Comment: @PHPHuppTechnologies now I'm getting `Variable &quot;user&quot; is invalid`, so I guess I'm still having the error. Remind you I'm returning a `JsonResponse`, working with Symfony, not just PHP.

Comment: Have you checked for more details? Whoever reads the data needs to parse them correctly, and by removing the backslashes that escape the `"`, you would return invalid JSON that nobody could parse

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, you're right. When I asked the question I didn't take that into account, I was thinking of the final user, so that's why I wanted to remove the `"`. But then I figured out that it's not necessary to do that, cause I'm seeing is a JSON, not what the final user will see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you are getting is perfectly fine.

The double-quote character needs to be escaped if it's part of a string, that's just the way it is.

You can always surround `user` with single quotes instead of double quotes, and then no escaping would be necessary.

Just have `$message` be: `"Variable 'user' is invalid"`.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But what I'm trying is to find a way to redefine that to make the JSON body look clear and fine to the final user.

Comment: If you are returning a JSON, you need to return a **valid** JSON. The "final user" should be someone or something that understand JSONs. So if you have to use the double-quote character, it simply **NEEDS** to be escaped. If you do not want it escaped, simply do not use a double-quote. As suggested on the answer, just use a single-quote instead.